# Symfony 3 Too many parameters

Tags: symfony, parameters, query-builder

I'm new to Symfony, and I got an error while running a query :

```
public function getFilteredArticles($page, $nbPerPage, $data) {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->leftJoin('a.images', 'i')
                ->addSelect('i')
                ->leftJoin('a.type_stockage', 't')
                ->addSelect('t')
                ->leftJoin('a.famille', 'f')
                ->addSelect('f');
        if ($data['famille'] != '') {
            $query->where('f.id = :famille')
                    ->setParameter('famille', $data['famille']);
        }
        if ($data['rds'] == false) {
            $query->where('a.stock_actuel > 0');
        }
        if ($data['recherche'] != '' && $data['recherche'] != null) {
            $query->where('a.ref_article LIKE :recherche')
                    ->setParameter('recherche', '%' . $data['recherche'] . '%');
        }
        $query->leftJoin('a.sousfamille', 's')
                ->orderBy('a.ref_article', 'ASC')
                ->getQuery();

        $query->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $nbPerPage)
                ->setMaxResults($nbPerPage);

        return new Paginator($query, true);
    }
```

This query have conditionnals parameters as you can see, that returns the list of articles I need for a table. But when I run this query to fill my table, I got the error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Too
>   many parameters: the query defines 0 parameters and you bound 1").

I don't know why he is expecting 0 parameters. I tried using setParameters instead, but the result is the same.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should use `andWhere()` methods instead of `where()`.
`where()` method removes all previous where, but `setParameter()` does not. That's why he found more parameters than where clauses.

I personally never use `where` if the condition has no sense to be the first condition, to avoid this kinds of errors.

```
    if ($data['famille'] != '') {
        $query->andWhere('f.id = :famille')
                ->setParameter('famille', $data['famille']);
    }
    if ($data['rds'] == false) {
        $query->andWhere('a.stock_actuel > 0');
    }
    if ($data['recherche'] != '' && $data['recherche'] != null) {
        $query->andWhere('a.ref_article LIKE :recherche')
                ->setParameter('recherche', '%' . $data['recherche'] . '%');
    }
```

`where()` php doc

> Specifies one or more restrictions to the query result.
>     Replaces any previously specified restrictions, if any.

`andWhere()` php doc

> Adds one or more restrictions to the query results, forming a logical
>     conjunction with any previously specified restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

My error, in Symfony 4, using Doctrine 2.6 was
`Too many parameters: the query defines 0 parameters and you bound 2`

The problem was that I wasn't defining the parameters in andWhere method as

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('q')
...
->andWhere('q.propertyDate IS NOT NULL') //this also couldn't find anywhere
->andWhere('q.parameterName = :parameterName')
->setParameters(['q.parameterName' => $parameterName, ...2nd parameter])
```

As I couldn't find any answer to my problem, but was similar to this one, I thought to maybe help someone who is struggling like I was.

Answer (score -2):

also in symfony 5 and 6  you should use andWhere() methods instead of where().
where() method removes all previous where, but setParameter() does not. That's why he found more parameters than where clauses.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to add some new insights